# Best way to module with reaction

Tags: javascript, mobx

So basically I'm developing this app with MobX (which I'm new to) and I have something that stumbled me.

I tried making it OOP like (don't know if it's good) and I have something in the likes of :

```
Store
  |- Filters (class)
        |- Filter (class)
  |- VisualData (class) 
        |- Property (class)
  |- Data (class)
```

Now, I need to derive the new VisualData (some calculation inside) based on dervied data of Data and Filters together.

Meaning, I'm fetching Data from the server and storing it in "Data". Then I'm setting filters and the visual data.

From there, every time I change the Filters, I need the VisualData to change as well.

The best I came up with was :

```
  updateVisualDataByFilters = reaction(
    () => toJS(this.filters),
    (filters) => {
      this.VisualData.setData(
        this.Data.getFilteredData(
          this.filters.getDataFilters,
        ),
      );
    },
  )
```

I had to use "toJS" otherwise it didn't register the change of this.filters - even though it did register in a computed function (which I also didn't understand).

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I don't know what kind of data you have in `setData`, but probably `computed` is going to be very suitable for your case. It is specifically designed for derived data. mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html

`reaction` is usually used when you need some sort of side effect, like make API call after filter change or something like that

Comment: I tried using computed, but since the data is in "Data" and I need to filter it by "Filters" I have to run a function and then set the derived data in VisualData. If I would have put everything in the same place I could probably use computed but seems a bit wrong to throw everything in a single store.

Comment: You don't need to have everything in single store, you can use DI to pass things around. For example inject `Filters` inside `VisualData`